# Laravel Polymorphic relationship get mixed collection

Tags: laravel, collections, polymorphism, relationship

I have an application that has a page that can have multiple block types linked to it in a certain order.
I have defined the following data structure:

```
page
    - id
    - title

block1
    - id
    - title

block2
    - id
    - title

page_blocks
    - id
    - page_id
    - block_id
    - block_type
    - weight
```

Inside the page I have defined 2 polymorphic relationships that allow me to link the blocks to the page as follows:

```
Class Page extends Model {
        ....

        public function block1() {
            return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Block1', 'block', 'page_blocks', 'page_id');
        }

        public function block2() {
            return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Block2', 'block', 'page_blocks', 'page_id');
        }
}
```

So now I can add blocks to a page, but I do have to use the correct relationship for every block. For example I can create a page like this:

```
$page = \App\Models\Page::firstOrCreate(['id' => 1], ['title' => 'Test']);

$block1 = \App\Models\Block1::firstOrCreate(['id' => 1], ['title' => 'Block 1 title']);
$block1_1 = \App\Models\Block1::firstOrCreate(['id' => 2], ['title' => 'Block 1.1 title']);
$block2 = \App\Models\Block2::firstOrCreate(['id' => 1], ['title' => 'Block 2 title']);

$page->block1()->sync([$block1->id => ['weight' => 1], $block1_1->id => ['weight' => 3]]);
$page->block2()->sync([$block2->id => ['weight' => 2]]);
```

In this case I want to have the following layout: item of type "Block 1", followed by item of type "Block 2", followed by another item of type "Block1".

If I want to fetch the blocks I can fetch them individually by type like this:

```
$page = \App\Models\Page::with(['block1','block2'])->find(1);
```

I was wondering whether there is a way to get all the blocks through the polymorphic relationship and get a mixed collection of Block1 and Block2 items in order of weight

Answer (score 1):

After you have both blocks using:

```
$page = \App\Models\Page::with(['block1','block2'])->find(1);
```

You can then just use collection functions to concat them and order them:

```
$blocks = $page->block1->concat($page->block2)
                       ->sortBy('weight');
```

You can learn more about the concat method here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-concat.